# What is the status of comprehensive comprehensions?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

[This proposed feature](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/SQLLikeComprehensions) looks really cool, and the page has the tantalizing assertion: "was integrated into GHCs HEAD branch on the 20th December 2007".

But I can't find much else about it.  What is the status?  If it is not part of the standard distribution what is the best way to achieve the same goals succinctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's there. The language extension is called `TransformListComp`. The syntax is a bit different than on the page you link. The extension is described here: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#generalised-list-comprehensions